# How to create object from class using a variable as name?

Tags: c#, class, constructor

For example we have the next class :

```
class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model {get;set;}
    public int Year {get;set;}
    public string Color {get;set;}
}
```

And a array with a few car models :

```
string[] cars = { "Honda", "BMW", "Audi"};
```

I want to create an object for each item in the array. I've tried with the next code but without success

```
foreach (var item in cars)
{
    Car item = new Car();
}
```

Comment: You could initialize a collection of your object and add to it each time through the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the same variable `item` in the loop. Plus the instances aren't really used as they disappear once the loop ends.

You might want to use [LINQ (a library used to manipulation collections)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)  and map the string names over to a collection of `Car` objects,

```
var makes = { "Honda", "BMW", "Audi" };
var cars = makes.Select(make => new Car(make));
```

For this to work however you need to add a constructor to your class that takes a makers name,

```
public class Car
{
    public Car(string make)
    { 
        this.Make = make;
    }

    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model {get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use class property initializer to set the Make property,

```
var makes = { "Honda", "BMW", "Audi" };
var cars = makes.Select(make => new Car { Make = make });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create your `Car` instance inside of `foreach`, you can't access these instances outside of  `foreach` scope. First create a `Car List` :

```
var carList = new List<Car>();
```

Then use a for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<cars.Length; i++)
{
   Car item = new Car();
   item.Make = cars[i];
   // set other properties
   carList.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set some info on the car, and somewhere to store all the instances.

```
        string[] carMakes = { "Honda", "BMW", "Audi" };
        List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();

        foreach (var carMake in carMakes)
        {
            cars.Add(new Car(){Make = carMake});
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model {get;set;}
    public int Year {get;set;}
    public string Color {get;set;}

    public Car(string make)
    {
        Make = make;
    }
}
```

And now for your loop:

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
foreach (var item in cars)
{
    Car car = new Car(item);
    cars.Add(car);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line with a little extra code

```
Car[] cars = new [] { new Car {Make = "Honda"}, 
                         new Car {Make = "BMW"}, 
                         new Car {Make = "Audi"}
                       };
```

or a Linq projection:

```
string[] cars = { "Honda", "BMW", "Audi"};
Car[] cars = cars.Select(s => new Car {Make = s})
                 .ToArray();
```

Comment: This code is wrong. You're converting to a Car[] not to a string[].

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to your class that accepts a 'make' parameter. The set it to the Make member on your instance.

```
class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model {get;set;}
    public int Year {get;set;}
    public string Color {get;set;}

  public Car(string make)
  {
       this.Make = make;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct each car like so:

```
foreach (var item in cars)
{
    // Note that you can't reuse 'item' here
    Car newCar = new Car { Make = item };
}
```

You will want to put each `newCar` in a list, or do something with it within the loop.

You could also use LINQ to do this in one line:

```
var carList = cars.Select(x => new Car { Make = x });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
foreach (string name in cars)
{
    Car item = new Car() { Make = name };
}
```